# How to mitigate spelling mistakes in Python properties?

Tags: python, properties, coding-style

I've read quite a bit about Python properties and I understand their benefits, as well as them being generally more Pythonic than getters/setters. However, I haven't found any mention of their usage being more prone to spelling mistakes leading to unexpected behavior for users, and I'd like to understand how this potential issue can be mitigated.

Consider the following example:

```
import datetime
import dateutil
class Person:
    def __init__(self, date_of_birth):
       self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth

    @property
    def date_of_birth(self):
        return self._date_of_birth

    @date_of_birth.setter
    def date_of_birth(self, value):
        # <Some checks about value>
        self._date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%d-%m-%Y').date()

    def compute_age(self):
        # Some computations involving today's date and self._date_of_birth
        return dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(datetime.date.today(), self.date_of_birth).years

# Compute age of someone
person = Person("15-06-1985")
person.compute_age() # Returns 38

# Update date of birth
person.date_of_birth = "17-08-2001"
person.compute_age() # Returns 22

# Update wrong attribute
person.date_of_brith = "25-11-1999" # No error or warning raised
person.compute_age() # Still returns 22
```

The last block of code is still perfectly valid, but `person` now has a useless `date_of_brith` attribute which is not used by `person.compute_age()`, while the intent of the developer was to update the actual date of birth of `person`. Since it generates no warning or error, this type of mistake could go undetected and yield unexpected results that are hard to debug in more complex applications. Using a setter method `person.set_date_of_birth()` instead of `person.date_of_birth` property would prevent such typos, since a typo in the method name would yield an exception upon execution. My question is therefore, doesn't that advocate for the usage of setter methods rather than properties? Otherwise, is there a clean way to mitigate this kind of spelling mistake when using properties?

Comment: That's what type checkers are for. For example, Pylance raises a warning: `"Cannot assign member "date_of_brith" for type "Person"
  Member "date_of_brith" is unknown"`

Comment: I would argue that a property setter should not *alter* the value being assigned. If you want/need to do that, use a regular method. The setter should only *validate* the given value, and either use it as-is or return an exception.

Comment: That's arguably incorrect behavior in Pylance (though I'm not sure if that's an optional check that can be disabled). Nothing in the code suggests that one *cannot* add such an attribute, even if it's not the intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fundamental property of Python that arbitrary attributes can be added to an instance. (There are exceptions, but we need not concern ourselves with them here.)

To prevent such accidental creations, we can override `__setattr__` to define what `person.XXX = ...` means. In this method, you can check that the attribute being assigned to is valid.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, date_of_birth):
       self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name not in ["_date_of_birth"]:
            raise AttributeError(f"Cannot create attribute named '{name}'")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    ...
```

Note that we do not need to add `date_of_birth` to the white list, because no *instance attribute* named `date_of_birth` exists. When attempting to assign to `person.date_of_birth`, the default behavior is to call `Person.date_of_birth.__set__` if it exists instead of creating the instance attribute.

That said, I would consider whether it is worth saddling your code with such a runtime check instead of making the user responsible for testing their code appropriately.

Comment: I'm not sure whitelisting every attribute is the best idea.

Comment: Because of my first paragraph, I'm not sure what the alternative would be. `setattr(obj, foo, bar)` is legal for any string value `foo` unless explicitly disallowed somewhere. (I'm purposely ignoring defining the type as a C extension because, aside from being a pain, that's an implementation-specific solution.)

Comment: Properly set type checker seems a solid alternative.

Comment: A type checker shouldn't (by default) flag such an assignment as an error, unless you have additional annotations that explicitly list the attributes to allow.

Comment: That's the same reason for flagging as this pylint warning - [attribute-defined-outside-init](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/attribute-defined-outside-init.html#attribute-defined-outside-init-w0201), which I think is a perfectly fine reason for a warning flag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, doesn't that advocate for the usage of setter methods rather than properties?

Comment: Perhaps, if your goal is to protect the user from every possible little error at the expense of bloated code. That's not a goal espoused by the Python community.